# X-FRAME-OPTIONS TO DENY

Tags: spring-mvc, modal, handlebars.js

Estou necessitando de um direcionamento. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação onde em uma das tela é permitido ao usuários visualizar um relatório especifico da página, para evitar que ao clicar na opção de gerar o relatório o mesmo fosse redirecionado para o relatório , criei uma forma que exibir ele em um diálogo estilo modal. (Até a parte de exibição do modal está funcionando)

Página do Modal

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="SAMEORIGIN">
</head>

<div class="modal  fade" id="relatorios" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" th:fragment="relatorios">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i>&times;</i></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Relatórios</h4>
            </div>

            <div id="modal_relatorio" class="modal-body">
                <div id="containerRelatorio"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <th:block th:replace="hbs/TemplateRelatorio"></th:block>
</div>

</html>
```

Utilizo um javascript para renderizar essa página com o auxílio do handlerbars

```
Pegasus = Pegasus || {};

Pegasus.Relatorio = (function() {

    function Relatorio() {
        this.relatorioBtn = $('.js-relatorio-btn');
        this.containerRelatorio = $('#containerRelatorio');
        this.source = $('#template-relatorio').html();
        this.template = Handlebars.compile(this.source);
    }

    Relatorio.prototype.enable = function() {
        this.relatorioBtn.on('click', onRelatorioClicado.bind(this));

    }

    function onRelatorioClicado(evento) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var botaoClicado = $(evento.currentTarget);
        var url = botaoClicado.data('url');

        var context = {url_relatorio: url};
        var html = this.template(context);
        this.containerRelatorio.html(html);
    }
    return Relatorio;
}());

$(function() {
    var relatorio = new Pegasus.Relatorio();
    relatorio.enable();
})
```

Template a ser renderizado:

```
<script id="template-relatorio" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <iframe id="frame-relatorio" src="{{url_relatorio}}" width="568" height="440" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</script>
```

A unica forma que conseguir para tentar meu objetivo foi usando o iframe, porém estou praticamente travado pois a mensagem de erro

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/pegasus/relatorios/fichaIdentificacao/2018000009' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Impede que o PDF seja exibido dentro do modal em questão. Mesmo com o meta do X-FRAME-OPTIONS estando com SAMEORIGIN no cabeçalho modal, não consigo sucesso, acredito que tenha que colocar essa informação dentro da função que gera o PDF

Função geradora do PDF:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import br.com.pegasus.service.RelatorioService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/relatorios")
public class RelatoriosController {

    @Autowired
    private RelatorioService relatorioService;

    @GetMapping("/fichaIdentificacao/{registro}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> gerarRelatorioFichaIdentificacao(@PathVariable("registro") String registro) throws Exception {
        byte[] relatorio = relatorioService.gerarRelatorioFichaIdentificacao(registro);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
                .body(relatorio);
    }

}
```

Alguém pode me auxiliar de como resolver esse problema, ou alguma outra forma de exibir esse PDF para o usuário?

PS: Uma informação que esqueci de adicionar, meu contêiner é o TOMCAT8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o sistema em questão está utilizando Spring Security, então encontrei a solução nessa resolução do stackoverflow [Solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security)

Com isso bastou apenas colocar nas configurações do sprinf security:

```
http
   .headers()
      .frameOptions()
         .sameOrigin()
         .and()
```

Antes das outras configurações que já tinha adicionado, que resolveu a questão do FRAME to DENY.